# SQL: Count distinct column combinations with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

I have a joined table that looks like this where **mytable** contains date, storeid, item and units, whereas **stores** has state and storeid.

```
date         state      storeid   item   units
==============================================
2020-01-22   new york   712       a      5
2020-01-22   new york   712       b      7
2020-02-18   new york   712       c      0
2020-05-11   new york   518       b      9
2020-01-22   new york   518       b      10
2020-01-21   oregon     613       b      0
2020-02-13   oregon     613       b      9
2020-04-30   oregon     613       b      10
2020-01-22   oregon     515       c      3
```

And I am trying to create a column that counts the unique number of times that both **storeid** and **item** occur in a row where the **date** is between a given date range and **units** is greater than 0. Also, only need to select/group by **state** and the calculated column. I have something that looks like this:

```
select
    s.state,
    count(distinct case
        when m.date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-03-31'
        and m.units > 0
        then m.storeid, m.item
    end) as q1_total
    from mytable as m
        left join (select
            state,
            storeid
        from stores) s
        on m.storeid=s.storeid
group by s.state
```

I know my count function isn't written correctly, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Trying to get the end result to look like this.

```
state         q1total 
=========================
new york      3
oregon        2
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Doing this in sql server. Also, edited the above to add the table name as "mytable." Thanks for flagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query:

```
select distinct state, storeid, item
from mytable
where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-03-31' and units > 0
```

you get all the distinct combinations of state, storeid and item under your conditions and you can aggregate on it:

```
select state, count(*) q1total
from (
  select distinct state, storeid, item
  from mytable
  where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-03-31' and units > 0
) t
group by state
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9e20edeee5d3eb289fe0720071f316f).
Results:

```
> state    | q1total
> :------- | ------:
> new york |       3
> oregon   |       2
```

Comment: Apologies, I should've clarified that this table view is based off a join. Edited above. I think what you have is right, but not sure how to tweak it. Edited the question above to show how it's being joined from two tables.

Comment: Change the FROM clause of the subquery to: `FROM (<your query here>) t`. Maybe it can be done without nesting your query but I can't tell since I don't have it.

Comment: Or create a CTE: `WITH mytable AS (<your query here>)` at the top of my query.

Comment: The CTE solution worked wonders for me. Thank you so much for the addition!